# Migrate webpack 2 to 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-4

I couldn't find any good source of knowledge.

How complex is to migrate from webpack 2.7 to version 4?

If my build time takes now 1 min 38 sec. will the version 4 boost it?

Are there any obstacles for doing it?

Have a nice friday!

Answer (score 6):

Just read the official documentation:

- Migrate to Webpack 3: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3
- Migrate to Webpack 4: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4

There shouldn't be any real obstacles other than that it always takes more time than one expects.

Comment: so I need to first migrate to v3 and then to v4?

Comment: @Ernesto technically yes. They are major version upgrades so it the practice to upgrade step by step.

Comment: @RuChernChong  My question is also, how to check which versions of webpack-dev-server and webpack-cli are needed for particular version of webpack itself?

Comment: It's all in the documentation though. If you're not feeling up for it, you could always start a new configuration based on Webpack 4, and then check for incompatibilities.